# If $X$ is a compact metric space then $C(X)$ is a separable space.

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, separable-spaces

While reading [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/757053/844467), I was a bit confused by the following :

> If $X$ is a compact metric space, then by Urysohn's Lemma and
> Stone-Weierstrass, the continuous functions $C(X)$ on $X$ are
> separable and hence the result follows as $C_{c}(X) = C(X)$.

I understand the use of Stone-Weierstrass because polynomial with rational coefficient are countable and are dense in polynomials with real coefficients which are dense (by stone-Weierstrass) in $C(X)$ when $X$ is compact. But I don't understand where Urysohn's Lemma comes into play.

Comment: "polynomials with real coefficients which are dense (by stone-Weierstrass) in C(X) when X is compact" this is wrong in an important way: You're given just that $X$ is a compact metric space, hence there's no such thing as a polynomial on $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $X$ is compact metric,  it has a countable basis $\{U_n\}_{n\in {\mathbb N}}$ of open sets.

For each pair $(n, m)$ such that $\overline U_n\subseteq U_m$, you can use Urysohn to pick some $f_{n, m}$ in $C(X)$ such that $f_{n, m}=1$ on $U_n$, and  $f_{n, m}=0$ on
$X\setminus U_n$.

The subalgebra $A\subseteq C(X)$ generated by  all of the  $f_{n, m}$ separates points of $X$, so it is dense by
Stone-Weierstrass.  Now you can finish your argument by pretending that $A$ is the algebra of polynomials.

Comment: Thank you. There is a technical point I don't get. The algebra generated by a countable number of elements is always countable?

Comment: No.  You must first consider the generated $\mathbb Q$-algebra, which is countable.  It's just like in your argument, where rational polynomials play an intermediate role.

Comment: When we say the subalgebra $A$ generated by all of the $f_{n,m}$ it means $\mathbb{R}$-linear combinations? So if I understand correctly the $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra is dense in the $\mathbb{R}$-algebra which is dense in $C(X)$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.